# Python sqlparse _ New line after ( in subquery

Tags: python-3.x, sql-parser

1. 

I am using " https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/discussions/761 "
My invoke program is
"

```
print(sqlparse.format(first, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper', ofrmt='python', wrap_after=8, indent_after_first=True))
```

2. 

How can I make the result

```
SELECT dt,
count(1)
FROM
(SELECT dt,
WEEK
FROM fin_dim.dim_m_y23_sixth_weekday_jwm_a)
GROUP BY 1;
```

to the below

```
SELECT dt,
count(1)
FROM
(
SELECT dt,
WEEK
FROM fin_dim.dim_m_y23_sixth_weekday_jwm_a
)
GROUP BY 1;
```

3. ie. I want to change the format of subquery without changing "count(1)".

Your reply is appreciated.

How can I be an expert in Python sqlparse, any suggestions.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Please edit your post and use the code mark for your program lines.

Comment: with sqlglot [link](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot)  , I face the same problem.
I want ( aligned with ) when there is subquery, what should I do